# Picture doesn't show up

Tags: html, css

Here is my website: [www.wostokhr.pl](http://www.wostokhr.pl)

In "div id="hero" i have picture "pics/hero.jpg" with JS parallax function. I have no idea, why this picture doesn't show up.  HTML and CSS validator didn't show any errors. Name and path of pic are correct. Any ideas how to fix it?

demo:

Comment: We can't really help you with this information.
A demo would be helpful. We don't know which picture you mean and where does it need to be shown on your website.

Comment: _“HTML and CSS validator didn't show any errors.”_ How about you check the JS console for errors?

Comment: maybe add ../pics/hero.jpg i dont know for sure but maybe your JS is the one who fetches the image so it is one level deep.

Comment: sorry u are right, here is demo : http://jsfiddle.net/0t8raq4r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make below changes

For HTML

```
<div class="parallax-mirror" style="z-index: 0 !important">
    <img class="parallax-slider" src="http://www.wostokhr.pl/pics/hero.jpg">
</div>
```

For Css

```
.parallax-slider{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

For JS

```
var strength3 = 200;
    $("html").mousemove(function(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
        var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
        var newvalueX = 1* pageX * -1;
        var newvalueY = 1* pageY * -1;
        $('.parallax-slider').css("left", (strength3 / $(window).width() * pageX * -1)+"px ");
    });
```

Comment: your solution works:) but i found real problem, div element hero has left float and sections below also have float left with grey background. I put clear both between these divs and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that rather than using `data-image-src="pics/hero.jpg"`, you use CSS to set the `background-image` property to your `pics/hero.jpg` path.
To do this, simply add:

`.hero { background-image: url("pics/hero.jpg"); }`

into your CSS file which will make the div class `hero` have the background image of the hero.jpg.
Hope this helped!

Comment: doing it in this way, pic show up, but parallax effect doesn't work ; /

Answer (score 0):

You can only change `z-index: -100;` to     `z-index: 0;` in `class="parallax-mirror"`

your parallax is working.